# How to use {dynamic_type} in in a dynamic template in the new ElasticSeach Java API Client

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-java-api

I have a dynamic template in which I use the special value `{dynamic_type}`, as I need it to work on every type that doesn't match any of my other templates. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-templates.html#template-variables)

My template is something along these lines (simplified from the real deal):

```
{
  "default-mapping": {
    "match_mapping_type":"*",
    "mapping": {
      "type": "{dynamic_type}",
      "copy_to": "__general_search"
    }
  }
}
```

ElasticSearch has moved to a new Java API Client and I want to migrate my code. (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api-client/current/introduction.html)

The old Java API was very weakly typed and you could specify basically anything you wanted, but in the new api you have to use specific builders/methods, which are different for each type. So for a text field you'd do something like `new Property.Builder().text(t -> t.copyTo("xyz"))`, for a boolean `new Property.Builder().boolean_(b -> b.copyTo("xyz"))`, etc.

My question is, how do I now specify the dynamic type (`{dynamic_type}`)? I can find no corresponding method/builder.

Update: I'm fairly certain this is bug/missing feature and have raised an issue for it at https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues/142

Answer (score 0):

It has been fixed and backported to 7.17 it seems.

See also:
https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-java/issues/142#issuecomment-1136153730